# Unable to use httpc module in my eunit test erlang.!`

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, eunit

Im writing my first test using enit in erlang. I managed to make some progress except that Im facing this error

```
 exit:{noproc,
{gen_server,call,
    [httpc_manager,
     {request,
         {request,undefined,<0.1634.0>,0,http,
             {"ody-staging-chatapi.toprpggame.com",80},
             "/",[],post,{...},...}},
     infinity]}}
```

I googled and found that we have to start inets like inets:start() and I placed that in my setup function but that did not solve the problem. Is there anything Im missing. Basically, Im calling httpc:request in my test and so the error.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Are you sure the `inets:start()` line is being called? Can you include your test code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, you can do two kinds of tests in Erlang. First is the unit tests, which is accomplished by `eunit`, and the second one is integration (or black box) tests with the help of `common tests`.

For eunit, it's best to mock external or 3rd party dependent calls (or libs) to get the best coverage, and so your tests will be consistent. [Here's an example](https://dreid.org/2011/06/13/meck-eunit-best-practices/).

If you want to do external calls, I suggest to do it in integration tests instead.